# Why won't my textures bake properly?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, texture-baking, baking

I posted another question earlier about trying to export my object keeping all the textures and materials intact and I was told the issue was that I haven't merged the meshes into one and UV unwrapped the result. I did attempt to do that but that process broke all my textures and I couldn't get them to go back to the way I had them before. I addition, the UV map became very messy and the seams didn't work the way they did before. I managed to get everything fairly straight and flat again, although some wouldn't straighten out at all, and also managed to get it so none of the islands were overlapping. But even after "fixing" the UV map, I still could not get the textures to go back on properly.

I was also told that I needed to bake the textures before merging them and apply those textures after the merge but now the issue I'm having is that the texture won't bake properly. It puts these weird lines over my texture and the texture image I'm trying to bake to is still just solid black. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I'm only very new to Blender.

Please help.

Here's what baking is doing to my texture:[image]

Versus what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

I'll also provide a link to my .blend files and textures, there are three .blends, one after baking, and one for before and after decimating the meshes as I'm not sure if decimating it is causing texture or UV issues or not, so I've provided both versions.
Link here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lJp7Q-mkAsGS8jgc3275Bb4qrNzEgJMF?usp=sharing

Comment: What's your target application? Unreal? *Or* why you'd like to *export* your object(s)?

Comment: Nah, I;m trying to make an armor mod for Fallout 4. Never made a full on mod or used Blender before though, so I'm struggling with some aspects. I know Fallout 4 uses .nif files for meshes and .dds for textures, which Blender doesn't output, so I;m using the program Outfit Studio to bridge between the file types and convert things for me.

Comment: The file types are not that relevant in the first place. Much more important is to find out the actual requirements for your bakes before baking anything, in fact a list of image types that are needed to match the appearance of the model in the engine  (when plugging the images into their shader models), e.g. Diffuse/Albedo, Normal (OpenGL or DirectX?), Roughness, Metallic etc. *and* whether it should be one object (one UV tile for all) or multiple objects (one UV tile each)...?

Comment: From what I can tell I need Diffuse, Normal and Specular images, as well as a Glow image if I had glow maps, but I don't for this mesh so no need to worry about that one. I'm pretty sure it should be one object as well as other mods I've unpacked to examine only see to have one texture per item. Not sure about much of the other info here, like I  said, I'm very new to any of this and I haven't really been able to find any in-depth, comprehensive tutorials about the process so I'm just doing my best to figure things out as I go.

Comment: Depends on the engine, recommend ask in their forums or something what's needed or just test it. Make a low-poly version of all your objects (your polycont is way to high), try to bake the normal map first (from high to low), then bake the other textures. Blender uses a newer shading model (metallic roughness) so don't expect the appearance to be *exactly* the same (there will be some loss).

Comment: Is there some method to specifically creating low-poly meshes? At least one's that don't look completely awful? Because I tried to make lower poly versions of things but they just looked blocky and horrible and as soon as I started trying to curve things, even just a little my counts went through the roof so I figured I'd just build everything and decimate it later, is that a bad way of doing things?

Comment: Decimate modfier doesn't help much in my experience. I'd model a simple shape with less polygons from scratch to get full control. Especially when it comes to baking the normal map, it's nice to be able to edit the shape while going back and forth in the process.

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time knowing how to model everything properly and keep the poly count down because I did model everything from basic planes and cubes but trying to do things like the straps seemed almost impossible without using things like bridge edge loops and solidify which ramped the polys waaayyy up. I also couldn't achieve very much in terms of decent curves and stuff without using subdivision surface which also seemed to increase the poly count by a huge amount.

Comment: Yep, there is a lot to learn and a lot to do to get it ported over properly.

Comment: You wouldn’t happen to know any good resources or tutorials on how to learn some of this stuff, would you? There’s obviously a ton of YouTube and stuff but the vast majority seem to be for animations or still renders where high poly counts don’t matter nearly as much and they don’t need to be exported or anything either. I’m really struggling to adapt the lessons in those videos to what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Youtube is a bad ressource in most cases when it comes to technical questions like this. Reading the manual and figuring out the requirements as suggested, is the quickest way IMHO. And/or split up your question into multiple chunks to make it "answerable". Good luck.